# Xcode Project: Different languages to different targets

Tags: ios, xcode, localization

I Have one project in Xcode ,this project have 4 different targets:

```
+Main Project
 -Target1
 -Target2
 -Target3
 -Target4
```

The project have 7 different languages in the localization:

```
En,He,Sw,Ch,It,Ko,Jap
```

I looking for a way to set for each target different languages.

FOR EXAMPLE:

```
+Main Project
     -Target1(En only)
     -Target2(He,Sw,Ch)
     -Target3(It,ch)
     -Target4(Jap only)
```

Comment: Why you don't use localization?

Comment: I use localization, but the localization is to all the targets in the project, that means that all the targets get the same languages

Comment: Have you tried copying the localized files to different folders, setting each of the files to different targets and configuring the localizations for each file? (@user2068793)

Answer (score 4):

You can set differents localization files for each target.

Just open Utilies, at target membership selected the targets you want to localize.

Example:

- en.string (mark target1 only)
- he.string, sw.string (mark target2 only)
- cd.string (mark target2 and 3)
- it.string (mark target3 only)
- [image: jap.string (mark target4 only)]

Comment: With Xcode 6, I have Localizable.strings, Localizable.strings (English), Localizable.strings (German), and target1, target2. If I unselect Localizable.strings (English) for target1, both of Localizable.strings, Localizable.strings (German) are unselected for target1 too. So I can not do as you said. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: @ZuzooVn unmark Localizable.strings (English) as a Target Membership of targe1

Comment: here is my detail question about this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31876602/can-not-select-localizable-for-each-target-for-ios-application

Answer (score 0):

use this answer [manual language selection in an iOS-App (iPhone and iPad)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939885/manual-language-selection-in-an-ios-app-iphone-and-ipad)

You can set any language you want, remember "Localizable.strings" for containing language text