# Specifying language for ipad applications

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

My Ipad application needs to have  a Settings Menu to select the language. I am planning to set the label with text

```
 self.myLabel.text = myStringVariable;
```

myStringVariable is set with an SQLite query similar to

```
SELECT myString from MyTable where Language='Italian' and id='myid'.
```

OR

```
SELECT myString from MyTable where Language='English' and id='myid'.
```

This means i need to keep an SQLite table with all the strings.Is it the right way? Or is there any built in  way to give the values hardcored inside the app which automatically changes the string values. In another words i am trying to AVOID the condition similar to the following for each label in my app.

```
if (Language==English) { self.myLabel.text = myStringVariable.....}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You should take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939885/manual-language-selection-in-an-ios-app-iphone-and-ipad).

Comment: You should probably [read this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html), especially the section Localizing String Resources.