# adding multi language and changing on button click

Tags: ios, localization, uikit

i'm new on xcode, i'm creating an app with multi language. i wanna to change language on button click.i'm searching for this and can't find any solution.i want 3 languages, English,Russian and Georgian.please write how to do this,or give me some tutorial video.thanks

Comment: You might want to check out this link for multi-language settings on ios https://www.raywenderlich.com/64401/internationalization-tutorial-for-ios-2014

Comment: thank for you attention

Comment: it\s good thanks, but i want to change it on button click

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939885/manual-language-selection-in-an-ios-app-iphone-and-ipad