# Localisation inside an iOS app without changing the system Language

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, localization

There is an option in my app that will enable the user to change the language of the app which can be different from the system's language.

The app has to be localised according to that language instead of the device's language.

I have found couple of solutions like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939885/manual-language-selection-in-an-ios-app-iphone-and-ipad) but I couldn't find a solution that will work for storyboards an base localisation.

How to achieve this?

Comment: Are you asking if there's a way in which you can do this without writing any code? If so, I seriously doubt it.

Comment: There is `PREFERRED LANGUAGE ORDER` section in settings that makes such settings redundant. Apple should start to decline apps with inner language switching to stop spreading that crazy idea.

Comment: @BenjaminLowry well, not necessarily. may be when the ViewController loads it is possible to specify a localisation file, or some other way that will not require setting all the texts programatically.