# How to change language of ios app in runtime itself with Base internationalizations swift 3?

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, localization

I have referred the below link as well as other links. I am able to change the language of the app after exiting.

Is there anyway I can change the language of the app with Base Internationalisation on the go?
For ex: If user selects English it should be reflected throughout the app.

[manual language selection in an iOS-App (iPhone and iPad)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939885/manual-language-selection-in-an-ios-app-iphone-and-ipad/10142363)

Comment: How are you changing language of data that we are getting from APIs at runtime?

Comment: @Amanpreet I have answered as well below. Check it

Answer (score 2):

This is how I did it. I created an extension on String class and created a `localized` variable which gets the string values from my `Localizable.strings` files of a language

```
public extension String {
    var localized: String {
        // currentLanguageCode is e.g. "en" or "nl"
        let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: LocalizationService.shared.currentLanguageCode, ofType: "lproj")
        let bundle = Bundle(path: path!)

        return NSLocalizedString(self, tableName: nil, bundle: bundle!, value: "", comment: "")
    }
}
```

Then everywhere in my code when I want to assign localized string values I do:

```
titleLabel.text = "settings_label_userProfile".localized
```

When user changes the language e.g. in my settings section, `LocalizationService` sets a different language code and from then on `localized` property will return the values of that language code. You need to make sure that the UI is reloaded if it's still displaying the previous language strings.

EDIT:

This solution will only work if you set your localizable strings programatically.

Comment: Ok. I get most of the part. Can you just give an example of your LocalizationService file?