# How to solve localisation issue?

Tags: ios, swift, localization

I am developing an app in Swift which supports two languages i.e. English and Norwegian.
I have gone through the documentation of Apple and applied the concept of Localizable.string and Localizable files for storyboard.

Now, I have an issue where a client wants to have whole app in Norwegian irrespective of system language.
I can achieve it by taking reference of each object in controller file and then assigning text based on localised string.

Could you please suggest more efficient way to handle this?

Thanks in advance.[image: Here is the screenshot of my project]

Comment: There are many similar questions already on SO. Refer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939885/manual-language-selection-in-an-ios-app-iphone-and-ipad

Comment: Please see below link. I had managed this in one of my app [Localization in Swift - Restrict app to one language even if the app has more languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46447630/localization-in-swift-restrict-app-to-one-language-even-if-the-app-has-more-la)

Answer (score 0):

Credit to [marmelroy](https://github.com/marmelroy) for this code https://github.com/marmelroy/Localize-Swift
which can Localize from within the app.

For your specific case,

1) You will simply need to drag and drop the required files from the above source

2) Set a line in `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`

```
// For Norwegian Nynorsk language.
Localize.setCurrentLanguage("nn")
```

This will set the current language to the needed one and will always show you the app in specified language.

Hope it helps!

**EDIT**

I tried the same and it's showing the auto suggestions for `Localize.set`
[image: Tried the same]

Comment: I am getting an error "Use of unresolved identifier 'Localize'"

Comment: Because, you have not followed the step 1. You should drag and drop 
files from here, https://github.com/marmelroy/Localize-Swift/tree/master/Sources except Localize_Swift.h (This is for MAC OS).

Comment: I have followed the steps and still it is not working. I guess there must be another issue.

Comment: see this once may be its helps you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52203442/ios-how-to-restart-app-for-changing-language-swift-4/52203769#52203769

Comment: Please update your question with the screenshot, How you are adding those 4 files

Comment: That seems to be ok. If you see the error "Use of unresolved identifier" then you should remove those files and add it again, tick copy items if need while adding. Also, restart your Xcode.

Comment: Thanks for your help.I have tried everything but it is not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Refer this [GitHub](https://github.com/micazeve/iOS-CustomLocalisator) Link to Change the Localisation  of the App in Runtime.