# Multilanguage application and .string file

Tags: objective-c, ios

I'm looking at some example of using `NSLocalizedString` and there is a .string file in project where i can find:

```
"Loading" = "Wczytuję...";
```

And then in a app code i can find:

```
return NSLocalizedString(@"Loading", @"");
```

How can i create multilanguage version of my app using that? Or there is a other way?

I want to have button to change language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly how you localize an iOS app. Everywhere where you want to show some localized text you write `NSLocalizedString(@"Something", @"Optional Description")`. Then you add a file called Localized.strings to your app's resources and translate the text there:

```
"Something" = "Something in other language";
```

You can add new languages by selecting the .strings file and on the right side of XCode add a new language:

[image]

You can also have additional, separate .strings files in your project. Then you have to specify where to look for a translation: `NSLocalizedStringFromTable(string, filename, comment)`

Comment: As i said - i don't want to do it by localization, i like to have button to change language.

Comment: You might want to make that clear in your question then. See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109245/changing-language-on-the-fly-in-running-ios-iphone-app