# Changing locale on the fly

Tags: ios, localization, nslocalizedstring

I want to change localization on the press of a button in my app

i have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5109245/changing-language-on-the-fly-in-running-ios-iphone-app) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6150576/change-ios-apps-language-on-the-fly)

I am changing my locale from english to hebrew and vice versa (LTR language to RTL language)

my layout is designed in such a way that it uses constraints from interface builder to determine the direction of the text and text fields.

If i do what these posts say, i get localized strings, but the constraints dont change, because the app needs a reboot to update the view direction

how do i make it update the view direction as well ?

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with this issue myself once, however I couldn't find any solutions to change the locale without restarting the app.

What I did was, I had a `setupUIForLocaleChange` method in every `UIViewController`. I call this method from `viewDidLoad` and I also send a notification everytime the locale changes and call this method. By "local change" I mean I had a manager with a property `locale`.
In my `strings` file, the strings have prefixes like "en.myString" and "es.myString", and I crated a macro like `LocalizedStringForKey(@"myString")` which returns `myString` with the current locale.
So I setup all my labels for the current local in these `setupUIForLocaleChange` methods, and you could do the same for your constraints as well, programmatically.

Hope this helps